# Old array reference in Dafny

Tags: dafny

Why does the assertion in the loop not hold while the assertion before the loop holds?

```
method m(a: array<int>, m: int)
modifies a;
requires 1 <= m <= a.Length;
{
    var k: int := 1;
    ghost var p_k: int;
    a[(k)-1], k, p_k := a[(k)-1]+1, k+1, k;
    assert old(a[..])[(p_k)-1]+1 == a[(p_k)-1]; 
    while k <= m
    decreases m-k;
    invariant 2 <= k <= m+1;
    invariant 1 <= p_k < k;
    invariant old(a[..])[(p_k)-1]+1 == a[(p_k)-1]; 
    {
        a[(k)-1], k, p_k := a[(k)-1]+1, k+1, k;
        assert old(a[..])[(p_k)-1]+1 == a[(p_k)-1]; 
    }
}
```

The purpose of the method is solely to understand the behaviour of `old` and `old` is used on purpose instead of ghost variables because in the end `old` is supposed to be used in a post-condition of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code so that assert inside loop verifies. See below:

```
method TestMethod(a: array<int>, m: int)
  modifies a
  requires 0 <=  m < a.Length
{
  var k := 0;
  a[k], k := a[k] + 1, k + 1;
  assert old(a[..])[k-1] + 1 == a[k-1];

  while k <= m
    decreases m-k
    invariant 0 <= k <= m+1
    invariant old(a[..])[k-1] + 1 == a[k-1]
    invariant forall i :: k <= i < a.Length ==> old(a[i]) == a[i]
  {
    a[k], k  := a[k] + 1, k + 1;
    assert old(a[..])[k-1] + 1 == a[k-1];
  }
}
```

Reason why assert inside loop is not being verified that before running loop body, dafny doesn't know that `old(a[k])` is equal to `a[k]`.